# select database router

Tags: python, django

How can I select the database router? I'm working with subdomains and if for example `app1.domain.de` is routed, I want to change the database router. Can somebody please help me?

```
    DATABASES = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
'default': {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',                                                                                                                                                                                            
    'NAME': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'db') + '/default.db',                                                                                                                                                                                
    'USER': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PASSWORD': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'HOST': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PORT': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
'app1': {                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',                                                                                                                                                                                            
    'NAME': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'db') + '/app1.db',                                                                                                                                                                           
    'USER': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PASSWORD': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'HOST': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PORT': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
'app2': {                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',                                                                                                                                                                                            
    'NAME': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'db') + '/app2.db',                                                                                                                                                                               
    'USER': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PASSWORD': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'HOST': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PORT': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
},                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}     

   DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app1.routers.DatabaseRouter', 'app2.routers.DatabaseRouter']   

  /app1/routers.py                                                                                                                                                             
  class DatabaseRouter(object):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         return "app1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

      def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):                                                                                                                                                                                                
         return "app1" 

/app2/routers.py                                                                                                                                                             
class DatabaseRouter(object):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        return "app2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):                                                                                                                                                                                                
        return "app2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The DB router should return the database name if its holding that model/table for requested model otherwise it should return `None`. In your case your routers always return `app1` or `app2` which is incorrect.

Here is sample about how I use it:

```
class AuditDBRouter(object):
    """
     A router to controll audit db operations
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on audit models to 'audit'"
        from django.conf import settings
        #admin do not want separate DB?
        if not settings.DATABASES.has_key('audit'):
            return None
        #return our DB name
        if model._meta.app_label == 'audit':
            return 'audit'
        #we don't serve this.
        return None
```

Comment: my problem is that only one router is called. only just one. always the same. the return none problem is just not implemented yet. i can't switch the routers :/ THANKS guy. hope you can help me

Comment: app_label is sometimes "sessions" or "auth" but both databases have users

Comment: The connection sessions doesn't exist! How can i handle auth and sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is what you want but you can achieve this behavior by simple using environment variables.

```
$ export DB_NAME=app1
```

After setting `DB_NAME` environment variable you can change your settings.py file like this to use this new var:

```
DATABASES = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  'default': {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',                                                                                                                                                                                            
    'NAME': os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'db') + '/' + os.environ.get('DB_NAME', 'default') + '.db',                                                                                                                                                                                
    'USER': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PASSWORD': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'HOST': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    'PORT': '',                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Please note that if `DB_NAME` is not set, `default` is the default value you'll end up with.